# Kernel for Gaussian Process

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am training a Gaussian Process (coded up in `scikit-learn`, see below).

I would like to understand how to make an educated guess for the kernels that could perform best for my task, by having a preliminary look at my signal. The mapping that the GP should be learning is between coordinates `x,y,z,d`, with `d = sqrt(x**2 +y**2 +z**2)`, and a scalar. The scalars for different coordinates `x,y,z,d` form together a time series.

Below I am plotting my training set, i.e. my time-series. In each plot, the `x`-axis represents one of the coordinates: `x,y,z,d`, respectively, ordered in ascending order and standardized. The components of the time series are ordered following this order, in each plot. In other words, in each plot I am showing my signal ordered as a function of the increasing `x,y,z,d` coordinate, respectively.

I would like to understand:

1) what is the best order for my data: as a function of `x`, `y`, `z` or `d`?

2) after having ordered my data according to 1), what is the best kernel to use in the Gaussian Process. In particular, what would be a reasonable prior choices for the initial hyperparameters and their ranges?

*TIME-SERIES ORDERED IN ASCENDING (STANDARDIZED) X COORDINATE*:
[image]

*TIME-SERIES ORDERED IN ASCENDING (STANDARDIZED) Y COORDINATE*:
[image]

*TIME-SERIES ORDERED IN ASCENDING (STANDARDIZED) Z COORDINATE*:
[image]

*TIME-SERIES ORDERED IN ASCENDING (STANDARDIZED) DISTANCE COORDINATE*:
[image]

**CODE**:

(As an illustrative example, here I am using a Matern 3/2 Kernel and I am ordering my data following increasing values of the `d` coordinate)

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import (RBF, Matern, RationalQuadratic, ExpSineSquared, DotProduct, ConstantKernel)
# Instantiate a Gaussian Process model
kernel = (time_series_ordered_with_increasing_d[:].std()**2.) * Matern(nu=1.5, length_scale=10.*np.ones(x_y_z_d_ordered_with_increasing_d.shape[1]), length_scale_bounds=(0.001, 20.0))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,  n_restarts_optimizer=10, alpha=time_series_ordered_with_increasing_d[:].std()/100.)

gp.fit(x_y_z_d_ordered_with_increasing_d, time_series_ordered_with_increasing_d[:])
print gp.kernel_
y_pred, sigma = gp.predict(x_y_z_d_ordered_with_increasing_d, return_std=True)
```